# Should Android Shell Commands Run With Java or Jni

Tags: java, android, performance, shell, java-native-interface

On android there are two methods to run shell commands either using java or using jni.

I was wondering if it is more efficient to run shell commands on one or the other.

Java

```
runtime.exec("su");
```

Jni

```
system("su");
```

Though I did hear that Jni doesn't accept multiple commands which might be a setback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism under the `Runtime.exec()` is `fork/exec` in native which is a more common and safe way to execute a command.

`system()` in jni use your current shell to interpret the command.

Moreover, you can use `fork/exec` in jni to execute command.

For the comparison of these two ways, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697440/difference-between-system-and-exec-in-linux).

Finally, it's hard to say which one is more efficient, both of them have to create a new process to handle the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with using http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1 .

I hope so that will be helpfull for you ;)