# What are the ways to create a new process in C?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, exec

I wonder are there any other ways to create a new process in C.
I know about `fork` which creates a child process.
Also, with `exec` I can replace the current executing program, but yet it does not create a new process.

Comment: Exec doesn't *create* a process. `posix_spawn()` and `vfork()` come to mind. Linux also has `clone()`, Windows has `CreateProcess()`...

Comment: There's also `system`. But unlike the others, it's not a system call.

Comment: `exec` doesn't replace the process; it basically replaces the *program* being executed by the current process.

Comment: Some ways have shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698608/8328237). You can read other answers of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697440/difference-between-system-and-exec-in-linux).

Comment: What are you trying to do, that you cannot do with `fork`, `clone` (fine tuned fork) and the `exec` (family)?

Comment: Thank you all, guys. I don't have a particular task. I was just interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware only `fork`, `vfork` and `clone` are used to create new processes in `linux`. (`posix_spawn` is not a syscall, but rather a library function which uses one of the syscalls above to create the process).

`exec` (and its sibling functions) is used to "mutate" a process, changing its memory layout according to the given ELF file.

###### (the example below is a very simplified version of the process, that leaves a lot of things out)

For example, when you run a command from your `bash` terminal, it uses `fork` (or clone). After the `fork` syscall, a new process is created and its memory layout is exactly the same as your `bash` terminal (To understand it better, read about `Virtualization` & `COW, Copy-On-Write`). Afterwards, the new process calls `execv` (or a similar function) to execute the ELF given to it by the command.